# Detect and remove Inputbox overflow

Tags: javascript, css, input, overflow

I have a input box with the attribute

> overflow:hidden;

I have also used javascript to stopped text being entered so that it cant overflow however I would like to be able to remove any overflow if the user manages to insert text into an already full textbox.

Is there anyway in javascript to detect when a texbox has hidden overflow? and remove it

Thanks

Comment: Are you just limiting the number or rows, characters, etc?  If thats teh case you should be able to just detect how many things have been typed and cap it.. But there are plugins to auto expand textboxes and whatnot if thats what your looking for, etc.

Comment: basically I wanted to remove any overflow the textbox may have on onunfocus=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to activly trim the text in the input box using javascript you can try:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clip()
{
    var maxLen = 3
    var box = document.getElementsByName('myInput')[0];
    if (box.value.length > maxLen - 1)
    {
        box.value = box.value.substring(0,maxLen - 1);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="myInput" onkeypress="clip()" />
</body>
</html>
```

this code is not pretty but it shows what you can do, every time the text in the text box gets to long the function trims the text(its a little stronger than what you asked but you can tone it down by changing the event to "onblur"). However, what etc suggested should usually work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set the max number of characters that can be entered?  If so:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="50" />
```